# Java summing numbers in an array using threads: using a new variable as a lock in a synchronized block: the difference

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, locks

I have an array of numbers that I sum using threads. To avoid the race condition issue, the block of code that increments the sum variables is wrapped in `synchronized`. At first I wrapped it in `synchronized (this)` and it worked fine.

However, I'm trying to understand what happens when something other than `this` is passed as a lock value. I tried to chance the lock to `synchronized (new Object())`, so that the lock value is different each time it executes. But it continued to work fine, although I'd expect it to break, because now the value - reference of the lock object changes each time:

```
public class SumNumbersCommon {
    private static int totalSum;
    private static int[] numbers = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception  {
        System.out.printf("Usual sum: %,d\n", sum(numbers));

        int left = numbers.length / 2;
        Thread leftThread = new Thread(new SummerThread(0, left));
        Thread rightThread = new Thread(new SummerThread(left + 1, numbers.length - 1));

        leftThread.start();
        rightThread.start();

        leftThread.join();
        rightThread.join();

        System.out.printf("total sum: %,d\n", totalSum);

    }

    static class SummerThread implements Runnable  {
        private int min;
        private int max;

        public SummerThread(int min, int max)  {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)  {
                synchronized (new Object()) {
                    totalSum += numbers[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static int sum(int[] numbers)  {
        int result = 0;
        for (int n: numbers)  {
            result += n;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Why does it still work? In which cases would I use anything other than `synchronized (this)`?

Comment: Works by chance (one thread finishes before the other one even starts for example). Try with more numbers.

Comment: Read up on `AtomicInteger`, which is a lot more efficient if all you want to do is protect an increment operation.

Comment: @JimGarrison I know of AtomicInteger, my understanding is that is uses synchronized inside? I want to understand how it works first before using wrappers

Comment: Burak's answer below is correct.  The problem is that with a data race, correct operation is not guaranteed.  However, *incorrect operation is not guaranteed either.*  Even though your code has a data race, there's still a non-zero chance that it will give a correct result.  Code that is incorrectly synchronized is ***indeterminate.*** It's output is random and cannot be predicted.

Comment: (That said it's possible to read code an make a guess whether it is likely to work or not, and why.  That's what Burak is doing.  He's probably correct (I can't think of a different explanation, and his seems likely) but it depends on a lot of things in a JVM, including how likely the optimizer is to use machine code instead of byte code and the timing of garbage collection.)

Comment: @parsecer It uses the native atomicity primitives of the hardware, not Java's `synchronized` functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Your threads are performing just a few trivial computations, so you don't have a chance to observe the data race. If you run the threads longer, you should observe inconsistencies.

`synchronized(this)` will use the monitor on `this`, so any other synchronized block and all synchronized methods of `this` will be serialized. In this particular example, `synchronized(this)` would be meaningless because `this` for both threads would be different. You need a shared object for locking.

`synchronized(obj)` can be used to control synchronization in a more fine-grained manner. Instead of blocking all synchronized methods of the object, this will only affect synchronized blocks that use `obj` as the locking object. This can be used in, for instance, modifying only a subset of the object state, or modifying some other shared state that is not part of the object state.

Comment: But `synchronized (new Object())` is meaningless and equivalent semantically to not synchronizing at all, except it runs a lot slower and consumes memory (unless the compiler is smart enough to figure that out and skip the synchronization).

Comment: `Your threads are performing just a few trivial computations, so you don't have a chance to observe the data race. `??? Updating a shared counter variable is a classic example of a race condition

Comment: btw using `synchronized(this)` is just as meaningless here. it's a comparison between two equally meaningless pieces of code.  Synchronization requires a shared lock.

Comment: @parsecer _...classic example of a race condition"_ yes but only if there's enough work so that the two threads actually run at the same time. In this case it's extremely likely one thread runs to completion before the other one gets a chance to start.

Comment: @parsecer There is data race. If you run the threads long enough you can observe the race more often. Not all executions will result in an observable race. Your threads are running quickly, so the possibility of observing the race is low.

Comment: I would really appreciate some simple examples (maybe pseudocode) that show when `this` is needed and when a fine-grained `obj` is needed...

Comment: @BurakSerdar What do you mean? The race is obvious. To increment a value 3 operations are needed: `1. save current value 2. increment saved value by 1 3. store updated value in the variable` if one thread started doing it and the other thread started doing it too before the first thread executed the step 3, the value won't be incremented twice.

Comment: @parsecer, yes the race is there, but there are many possible execution orderings. The fact that the result differs based on the execution ordering is what's called a race. In your case, the possibility of correct output is much larger than the possibility of incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

The point of locking is to prevent concurrent access to shared data. That means that the different threads trying to access the data need to all use the same lock. The posted examples don't do that, the separate threads are each using their own lock, so no kind of useful locking is taking place.

To change this so that you have meaningful locking, move the actual shared data into its own class, and pass the shared data object into each thread.

Here's an example of what the shared data class could look like:

```
public class RunningTotal {

    private int totalSum = 0;
    private int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    public void synchronized addNumberAtIndex(int idx) {
         totalSum += numbers[idx];
    }

    public synchronized int getTotalSoFar() {
        return totalSum;
    }
}
```

Here the object controls access to its data using its own intrinsic lock, any thread that wants to update the running total needs to acquire the lock on that object first.